# How to compile projects in Xcode with make files

Tags: xcode, makefile, compilation, linker

I have a question , if I have a makefile with which help I can compile my source code in terminal , but how can I do the same with Xcode , and does Xcode need makefiles always when we compiling project ? I actually don't understand how linker works with makefiles , why it works perfectly with the small projects and why ( if not ) I can't either compile a huge project without makefiles.

Im new in  makefiles...

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I too would like to use Xcode and get compilation errors reported in Xcode, I have a pretty sophisticated CMake file and compiling through CLI works fine using the makefile, but I get get it setup properly using Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an external build system project to use makefiles in Xcode. Most of Xcode's project templates are designed to use Xcode's build system, not makefiles.

You can find the external build system project template in the Cross-Platform section of the New Project Assistant.

[image]

When you click the Next button, you will notice the project is already set to use make as the build tool.

Comment: yeah , and i will be able to use breakpoints and debugging and other xcode stuff ?

Comment: Xcode is designed to create iOS and Mac apps using Swift or Objective-C. Any other use of Xcode is not supported as well by Apple. If you use an external build system project, you do not have access to all of Xcode's features. If you want to use all of Xcode's features, use Xcode's build system instead of makefiles.

Comment: but if I want to compile project , its seems that linker actually doesn't know how to link it, even if I customize searching paths

Comment: I answered your original question on how to use makefiles in Xcode. If you are having trouble linking your project, ask a new question.

Comment: FWIW, Apple does support C++ and C. If you are creating a Command Line Tool with Xcode for macOS, you can select one of the following languages: Swift, Objective-C, C++, C. https://developer.apple.com/xcode/cpp/
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10172/